# How goBack screen in test with detox

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, detox

I make **automatization** react native test with **detox**, It has the next screen sequence `A -> B -> C` and i wish to go back to the screen `B <- C.`
Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

You could go ahead and create a utility

```js
export const pressBack = async () => {
  if (device.getPlatform() === 'android') {
    await device.pressBack();
  } else {
    await element(by.traits(['button']))
      .atIndex(0)
      .tap();
  }
};
```

- Android: [device.pressBack()](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.DeviceObjectAPI.md#devicepressback-android-only)
- iOS: [go back last screen #828](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/828#issuecomment-404880787)

Answer (score 3):

There's a testId on the back button, so you can do this:

```
  await element(by.id("header-back")).tap();
```

Comment: This worked for me on the following environment:
    Xcode: 11.5
    react-native: 0.61.5
    "detox": "^16.8.2",

Answer (score 2):

sometimes

```
await element(by.id("header-back")).tap();
```

does not work and

```
await element(by.traits(['button']))
  .atIndex(0)
  .tap();
```

selects another button. In that case, you can try to use swipe right on ios assuming that it is a stack navigator. Use the outer container view

```
await element(by.id('containerView')).swipe('right', 'fast', 0.1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `react-native-navigation` you can use:

```
const backButton = () => {
  if (device.getPlatform() === 'ios') {
    return element(by.type('_UIBackButtonContainerView'));
  } else {
    return element(by.label('Navigate Up'));
  }
};
...
await backButton().tap();
```

For iOS in `detox@17.3.6` & `react-native-navigation@6.10.1` you can use:

```
return element(by.id('pop'));
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to use traits button as follows:

await element(by.traits(['button'])).atIndex(0).tap();

Answer (score 1):

Another way that works is

```
await element(by.id('header-back')).atIndex(0).tap()
```

This uses the built in testID that the default back button that comes with react-navigation v5. You may need to mess with the atIndex() number since for me it seems to match 2 back buttons but the first one was the one I was looking for.