# Detox: How to close iOS native video player?

Tags: detox

I'm using Detox for e2e test. And my app has media-files, that open with iOS native player.
I must check that video-preview item(that I heat to open the video).   not.toBeVisible().
And the final check is required: close the media player (hit the cross button or swipe down) and verify that the previous screen has been observed.

Research by stackoverflow - [51309796](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309796/how-goback-screen-in-test-with-detox)  does not resolve an issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93f5a.jpg)

```
    await teaserElement.tap();
    await expect(teaserElement).not.toBeVisible(); //not visible as the video layer opened
    await element(by.traits(['button'])).atIndex(0).tap()
   //await element(by.traits(['none'])).atIndex(0).swipe('down');
    await expect(teaserElement).toBeVisible(); // observed as the video player has been closed
```